# Rails: Stylesheet/view issue? Nothing is showing on the screen although there is source code when viewed in browser

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have a rails app with many partials for one view, each partial is a section in the view (one paged website).
I have put all my assets in the correct places etc.
below is a screenshot of how the actual page should look (outside of rails) (header, then section one which you can see, and there are sections below etc).

[image]

However this is how it is showing when done in rails
[image]

No images are shown for some reason, nor any content. 
When I do not include the style sheet, all the content (writing) shows fine. When I include the stylesheet, everything disappears, its all white. However there are content there because I am able to scroll up/down.

Below is a screenshot of the structure of my files 
[image]

I basically have all my images inside the image folder, but there are subfolders inside the image folders.
so:

```
assets (folder)
 images (folder)
  section_1 (folder)
   image.png (file)
```

in my css, because my css files are inside the stylesheets folder, I call my urls as follows:

```
background-image:url("../images/section_1/image.png");
```

As for my views, it is basically one view which renders out each section (partial).

Comment: Have you checked your application.html.erb file?   `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>`

Comment: That doesn't come into the picture (at least I think) because the layout rendered is my own, not the default application (which uses the application.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `background-image:url("section_1/image.png");`

This works in my rails project. However, I'm using compass, so it might be different.

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is. But I still have one more problem.
The solution.
When calling an image from anywhere, even if you have a sub directory like I have, you simply call the url as follows:

```
background-image:url("assets/header/header_bg.png")
```

So you basically leave out the images folder for some reason.

The problem I still have is a routing issue.
In my assets folder I have a folder named fonts.
Inside this folder I have a number of folders, with different fonts in each folder (.eof,.ttf.svg) the usual font files.

When I type in the exact url of where these files are stored I get a routing error.

I also have a file called fonts.css in my stylesheet folder.
In the url if i put `localhost:3000/assets/fonts` which is the folder of the fonts I get a routing error.

Is there anyway in the routes file can I route the application correctly?

Both for the images and for the fonts?